# MySQL ODBC Connection Select Fails

Tags: mysql, odbc

I am trying to do a very simple sql select statement from a MySQL database:

```
     Dim lDatabase As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("FTP")
     lSqlString = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "SELECT monthends.web_usr FROM monthends")

     lDBCommand = lDatabase.GetSqlStringCommand(lSqlString)
     lUsers = lDatabase.ExecuteDataSet(lDBCommand)
```

And on the execute dataset line I receive the following ODBC Exception:

In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly supplied by the user.

I don't get it. This is the simplest of simple sql statements and it has all worked just fine in the past, why doesn't this work anymore???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What changed between "it has all worked just fine in the past" and "today"?
Is a primary key / index defined on the Table monthends?

Comment: Nothing had changed. I was working on a clients machine as a contractor and it had the wrong version of MySQL ODBC 3.5xx installed. Once I got the correct version it worked.

Answer (score 0):

What was going on was that there was an incorrect version of the MySQL ODBC 3.5xx driver installed. I contacted the DB Admin and got the correct version, it all works now as it should.